# Cannot declare class WishList when activate Prestashop Theme

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I uploaded theme in prestashop 1.7. When I want to install it i'm getting error 500, i turned on debug mode and now I see this error:
**Compile Error: Cannot declare class WishList, because the name is already in use**

And here is the code of this error:

```
in modules/leofeature/classes/WishList.php (line 566)
        return Db::getInstance()->executeS('            SELECT wp.*            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'leofeature_wishlist_product` wp            WHERE wp.`id_wishlist` = '.(int)$id_wishlist.'');    }}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed another module with a class of the same name : WishList